# Green functions of interacting Bose gas

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, greens-functions

It is well-known fact that the appearance of superconducting state in superconductor relates to the existence of the pole in two-particle Green function.

Does exist a similar fact for Bose condensation?

I mean the following: one can compute a Green function of interacting Bose gas and see that a singularity of this function corresponds to appearance of condensate state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bose-Einstein condensation is not caused by interaction: ideal Bose gas undergo Bose-Einstein condensation. In contrast, superfluidity is due to interaction and one should see its signature in Green functions as a pole associated to phonons.